# How to use tf.assertDtypeEqual to test dtype of tensor

Tags: unit-testing, tensorflow

I am having a tensor

```
t = tf.io.decode_raw(tf.constant('asdf'), tf.uint8)
print(t.dtype)
<dtype: 'uint8'>
```

I want to validate this dtype using function from tf.test.TestCase. I am using below function

```
self.assertDTypeEqual(t.dtype, tf.uint8)
```

but it is giving me an error

```
TypeError: Cannot interpret 'tf.uint8' as a data type
```

Please let me know how to validate tensor datatype using tf.test.TestCase?

Answer (score 1):

tried your case and i ran with tensorflow 2.3, seems it took the string as an input

```py
import tensorflow as tf

class dtype_testcase(tf.test.TestCase):
    def setUp(self):
        super(dtype_testcase, self).setUp()
        
    def tearDown(self):
        pass
    
    def test_dtype(self):
        data = tf.constant([1,2, 3], dtype=tf.uint8)
        self.assertDTypeEqual(data, 'uint8')
        
        
if __name__ == '__main__':
    tf.test.main()

[       OK ] dtype_testcase.test_dtype
[ RUN      ] dtype_testcase.test_session
[  SKIPPED ] dtype_testcase.test_session
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 2 tests in 0.394s
```